# Limit Number of List Items to Display in Python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of users in id1 and id2.  I want to be able to limit the number of users that are shown as a result of user input.  For example, if there are 100 in x.  I want to be able to input 25 to only show 25 users

```
id1 = ([u.id for u in userlist1])
id2 = ([u.id for u in userlist2])

x = set(id1) - set(id2)

numshow = raw_input('How many do you want to show? ')
print 'Now showing ' + numshow + ' users'

usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x)

for num in usershow[:numshow]:
    next(usershow)
```

I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: use `[]` instead of `()` - `usershow = [...]`

Comment: or use `[:numshow]` inside generator `(api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x[:numshow])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[:numshow]` inside generator to get only `numshow` users from api.

```
usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x[:numshow])

for user in usershow:
    print(user)
```

**EDIT:** as @TigerhawkT3 notices `x` is `set` so you have to convert `x` into `list`. Correct version is

```
usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in list(x)[:numshow])

for user in usershow:
    print(user)
```

---

Or you have to convert generator to list

```
usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x)

for user in list(usershow)[:numshow]:
    print(user)
```

You can also use range - but if there is less users than `numshow` then you get error `StopIteration`.

```
usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x)

for num in range(numshow):
    user = next(usershow)
    print(user)
```

---

**EDIT:** using `islice` you don't have to convert anything into list.

```
import itertools

usershow = (api.ShowUser(user_id=usershow) for usershow in x)

for user in itertools.islice(usershow, numshow):
    print(user)
```

---

**BTW:** if you use `usershow` with `for` then you don't need `next()` and I had to use `next()` only in one example.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you are right, I didn't notice `set()`